# Altering MySQL auto increment via a PDO query?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do this:

```
$resetAI = $db->prepare("ALTER TABLE `lotteries` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");

$resetAI->execute();
```

I tried doing it except it's not resetting, can I only do this via PMA or what?

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? What's the output of `print_r($resetAI->errorInfo())`?

Comment: I did that and it returned `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

I have no idea...

Comment: Does `lotteries` table already have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key?

Comment: Yea it has `lid` and it's set at 12, I want it to reset to 1 but I need to do it via a query.

Comment: OK I don't know why it would print over and over like that, but that means there's no error (in the errorInfo array, 0 = SQL error code, 1 = driver error code, 2 = error message)

Comment: I accidentally had it in my foreach, that's why.  However, it's still nopt updating. :S